# Testing against multiple Vagrant versions using Travis-CI

Tags: vagrant, travis-ci

I'd like to test my Vagrant plugin against multiple versions, using for each release the same ruby version embedded with the Vagrant package. I've created the following configuration file for Travis CI:

```
language: ruby
matrix:
  include:
    - rvm: 1.8.7-p357
      gemfile: gemfiles/vagrant1_1.gemfile
    - rvm: 1.9.3-p448
      gemfile: gemfiles/vagrant1_2.gemfile
      gemfile: gemfiles/vagrant1_3.gemfile
    - rvm: 2.0.0-p353
      gemfile: Gemfile
```

But when I try to validate this configuration against the Travis Lint web service I receive the following error:

**Found an issue with the rvm key:**

**Specify Ruby versions/implementations you want to test against using the "rvm" key**

First experience with Travis CI, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis seems to require that you specify at least one default `rvm`. Like:

```
language: ruby
rvm: 2.0.0
matrix:
  # ...
```

Other issue is that I'm quite sure the second `gemfile` in '1.9.3-p448' will just override the first one.

And third, Vagrant officially supports only one Ruby version. Before 1.4 Vagrant only works with Ruby 1.9.3, from 1.4 on with Ruby 2.0.0. You might not hit problems in plugin's unit tests, but no need to consume Travis resources. =)

For env var based approach (instead of Gemfile based), see vagrant-proxyconf's [.travis.yml](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/blob/ff1b7ee9cda2b93848f21807c16e89690e3813c5/.travis.yml) and [Gemfile](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/blob/ff1b7ee9cda2b93848f21807c16e89690e3813c5/Gemfile).

---

Comment: Really like your env var approach. Thank you.

Comment: Env var is nice as you can also set it to wanted version when developing. So no need to pass the gemfile to all bundler commands.